# ErrorException Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce\resources\views

Tags: laravel

I am working on an E-commerce application, I want to retrieve an order together with it's associated products but I couldn't get pass that error, I don't know what am missing there. Thanks for help. Here is my code.

```
public function show(Order $order, Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', $request->order->id)->first();
    $products = $order->products();

    // dd($products);
    return view('orders.order')->with([
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

And if I dd($products) I got null

This is my views

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
     <li class="">
         {{ $product->id }}
     </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You can't do `foreach()` on `null`; you already know the source of your error. Try `$order->products` or `$order->products()->get()`; `$order->products()` is a `Builder` instance, which, while it shouldn't be treated as `null`, might be the cause of your error. If that doesn't work, share your `public function products()`; there might be something wrong with your relationship

Comment: Ok let me try edit the code.

Comment: guess: missing the return statement in that method :)

Comment: Yes I was missing the return statement in products relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `products()` is a relationship in your `Order` model, `$order->products()` will return an instance of `Builder`.

To get the products, you can simply do:

```
$order->products
```